# how to calculate % of row and % of column for a python pivot with row and column headings?

Tags: python, pandas, pivot, percentage

For this simple pivot, how to turn value into % of row, and likewise to % of column?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['one', 'one', 'two', 'three'] * 3,
                   'B' : ['A', 'B', 'C'] * 4,
               'C' : range(12)})
pd.pivot_table(df, index='A', columns='B', aggfunc=sum)
```

Somehow after some searching I don't find answer to this simple question.

Expected result (if getting % of column)

```
      A   B  C
ONE   50% 24% 50%
THREE 13% 31% 42%
TWO  36% 45% 8%
```

Thanks

Comment: What do you want your expected output to look like?

Comment: i've updated question, basically the equivalent of excel show value as % of column/row. thanks

Comment: Try `pd.crosstab(df.A, df.B,values=df.C,aggfunc=np.sum,normalize='columns')`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can the desired output by using [`pd.crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['one', 'one', 'two', 'three'] * 3,
                   'B' : ['A', 'B', 'C'] * 4,
               'C' : range(12)})

pd.crosstab(df.A, df.B, values=df.C, aggfunc=np.sum, normalize='columns')
```

This should yield:

```
B             A         B         C
A                                  
one    0.500000  0.227273  0.500000
three  0.166667  0.318182  0.423077
two    0.333333  0.454545  0.076923
```

You can reformat the output to display the percentages in hundredth with `applymap`:

```
pd.crosstab(df.A, df.B,values=df.C,aggfunc=np.sum,normalize='columns').applymap(lambda x: "{0:.0f}%".format(100*x))
```

This should yield:

```
B        A    B    C
A                   
one    50%  23%  50%
three  17%  32%  42%
two    33%  45%   8%
```

#### Edit:

If the `normalize` parameter is not working, you can get the percentage with `apply`:

```
pd.crosstab(df.A, df.B, values=df.C, aggfunc=np.sum).apply(lambda x: x/x.sum()).applymap(lambda x: "{:.0f}%".format(100*x))
```

I hope this proves useful.

Comment: thank you Sir! however it returns an error 
TypeError: crosstab() got an unexpected keyword argument 'normalise'
do i need additional package other than pandas and numpy? i'm on python2

Comment: It's `normalize` not `normalise`. You seem to be using the British spelling here, while the argument is spelled the American way (with a `z`). Also, you only need `pandas` and `numpy` for this. If you don't want to use `numpy`, you can switch `aggfunc=np.sum` with `aggfunc=sum`.

Comment: curiouser and curiouser. it doesn't recognise 'z' either.                else:
     87                     kwargs[new_arg_name] = new_arg_value
---> 88             return func(*args, **kwargs)
     89         return wrapper
     90     return _deprecate_kwarg

TypeError: crosstab() got an unexpected keyword argument 'normalize'

Comment: You may be using an older version of `pandas`. Is it possible for you to upgrade the `pandas` you have installed on your machine? You may use `pip install -U pandas` for it. I am using version `0.19.2`.

Comment: thank you. apply worked. somehow wasn't able to upgrade pandas

Answer (score 5):

This will give you the desired result

```
df = pd.pivot_table(df, index='A', columns='B', values = 'C', aggfunc=sum).apply(lambda x:100 * x / float(x.sum())).round(2)
```

I have done it as a one liner but you can break-up pivot and apply

You get

```
          A      B       C
  A         
 one    50.00   22.73   50.00
 three  16.67   31.82   42.31
 two    33.33   45.45   7.69
```

Answer (score 0):

With [pandas.crosstab](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html?highlight=crosstab#pandas.crosstab) you can achieve what you need really easy.

Notice that **normalize** could be by columns or by rows (now called index) regarding what you need.

```
pandas.crosstab(index=df['A'],columns=[df['A'], df['B'], df['C']],normalize='columns')
pandas.crosstab(index=df['A'],columns=[df['A'], df['B'], df['C']],normalize='index')
```

Comment: Note that I think the syntax has changed and it's not `rows` but `index` you need to pass to the `normalize` parameter for the desired effect